# Mac readline - Library not loaded

Tags: mac, readline

I'm working on a Mac, Sierra 10.12.3, and I'm trying to access a PostgreSQL database via the `psql` command, but it threw the error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

A day or two ago, I was working with someone and I needed to install pip, so I ran `brew install pip`, and it was all good. This is the first time I'm trying to run `psql` since then and I'm not certain that this has anything to do with my problem, but it seems likely since I haven't made any other changes.

Now I did a little detective work and found that if I went to `/usr/local/opt/` there was indeed a `readline` alias directory that pointed to `/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.1` (version 7.0.1 also seeming to have gotten installed at some point - maybe as part of pip? Maybe I did it by mistake...) so it made some sense that the original error should be thrown. I changed the alias to point to `/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.3.8` and the error changed slightly:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib: stat() failed with errno=20
Abort trap: 6
```

So it seems like I'm getting *somewhere*, but still having an issue. If anyone can shed some light on a solution, I would be forever grateful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by simply running `brew switch readline 6.3.8`

Comment: Hmm, readline is already on v8.0.0

Comment: Works for me ... slightly altered:
Error: readline does not have a version "6.3.8" in the Cellar.  
readline installed versions: 6.2.4, 7.0.5, 8.0.1  

➜ brew switch readline 6.2.4

Answer (score 7):

Running
    `brew upgrade gawk`
worked for me, as suggested by [@wisbucky](https://superuser.com/users/139045/wisbucky)

And that fixed the below error, upon opening a new terminal :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/awk
```

OS details:
macOS Mojave
version 10.14.1 (18B75)

Answer (score 3):

my issue was due to my awk being linked to gawk

`brew unlink gawk`

Comment: While that works, you will be removing the symlinks to `gawk`, which means `gawk` won't work anymore. To keep `gawk`, upgrade it with `brew upgrade gawk`. That will also update the `readline` version since it's a dependency. Or if you don't want `gawk`, then `brew uninstall gawk`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a symlink

```
ln -s /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.dylib /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

so the message in my case was.

> Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.8.0.4

and based on [@skwidbreth's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1181335/703240), I was able to figure out that I had 8.0.4 already installed, I just needed to switch to it:

```
brew switch readline 8.0.4
```